# Get all non-unique values (i.e.: duplicate/more than one occurrence) in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to check a JavaScript array to see if there are any duplicate values. What's the easiest way to do this? I just need to find what the duplicated values are - I don't actually need their indexes or how many times they are duplicated.

I know I can loop through the array and check all the other values for a match, but it seems like there should be an easier way.

#### Similar question:

- [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473)

Comment: There seems to be years of confusion about what this question asks. I needed to know what elements in the array were duplicated: "I just need to find what the duplicated values are". The correct answer should NOT remove duplicates from the array. That's the inverse of what I wanted: a list of the duplicates, not a list of unique elements.

Comment: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/4852#issuecomment-666366511 I would add this as an answer, but given the length of answers, it would never be seen

Answer (score 373, accepted):

You could sort the array and then run through it and then see if the next (or previous) index is the same as the current. Assuming your sort algorithm is good, this should be less than O(n<sup>2</sup>):

```js
const findDuplicates = (arr) => {
  let sorted_arr = arr.slice().sort(); // You can define the comparing function here. 
  // JS by default uses a crappy string compare.
  // (we use slice to clone the array so the
  // original array won't be modified)
  let results = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < sorted_arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) {
      results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return results;
}

let duplicatedArray = [9, 9, 111, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7];
console.log(`The duplicates in ${duplicatedArray} are ${findDuplicates(duplicatedArray)}`);
```

In case, if you are to return as a function for duplicates. This is for similar type of case.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57532964/8119511

Comment: Emil, your edit was correct, thanks. :) I just say "Oh squared".

Comment: "Assuming your sort algorithm is good, this should be less than O^2".  Specifically, it could be O(n*log(n)).

Comment: And this is the best you can do in the comparison model.

Comment: @swilliams: What if the array is an array of html elements, how do you sort them 1st?!

Comment: This script doesn't work so well with more than 2 duplicates (e.g. `arr = [9, 9, 9, 111, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7];`

Comment: Instead of `i += 1` you can write `i++`.

Comment: @danilo I know, though I tend to follow Crockford's advice on not using that pattern in JS. http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Comment: @swilliams I don't think those guidelines say anything about not using `i++`. Instead, they say not to write `j = i + +j`. Two different things IMHO. I think `i += 1` is more confusing than the simple and beautiful `i++` :)

Comment: The sample script currently alerts "4,9". Thats a huge failure. This thing is broken

Comment: This script is broken, it assumes an array made entirely of duplicates (i.e. if you have a single value without a duplicate in the array the script will generate a wrong result)

Comment: for long arr, you might consider removing arr.length from the head of the loop as on old browsers (specifically IE) this considerable drops the looping speed.

Comment: This script is broken: the sort function for string compare *will not work* for numbers! Also you need another i++ for when...nevermind, I'll fix it.

Comment: I rollbacked last edit because it was leading to an error with i=arr.length-1.

Comment: -1 This answer is wrong on many levels. First of all `var sorted_arr = arr.sort()` is useless: `arr.sort()` mutates the original array (which is a problem in its own right). This also discards an element. (Run the code above. What happens to 9?) cc @dystroy A cleaner solution would be `results = arr.filter(function(elem, pos) { return arr.indexOf(elem) == pos; })`

Comment: @NullUserException I'll take no responsibility for this answer : I just fixed the i+1 being to big. In fact I just rollbacked an edit. I know I answered (with many tests) another similar question but I don't have the link...

Comment: Everyone: the question asks to display the duplicate values, not to remove them. Please don't edit/break the code to try to make it do something it's not trying to do. The alert should show the values that are duplicated.

Comment: This is short, although sorting it is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Although this isn't what the OP asked, Google brought me here when I was searching for a quick way to remove duplicate values from an array. So +1 anyway.

Comment: Like Mottie mentioned above, this snippet doesn't know work when there is more than 2 duplicated values, ex array like this [3,3,3,1] will not work

Comment: instead of looping through the sorted array you could use `sort((x,y)=>{if(x===y) duplicated.push(x)})`

Comment: Maybe can be better if change the if to `if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i] && results[results.length-1]!=sorted_arr[i])`

Comment: This does work. It gives back ALL duplicates sorted, which you might not want. There are better (simpeler, shorter) solutions  like https://stackoverflow.com/a/31017485/760777

Answer (score 215):

If you want to elimate the duplicates, try this great solution:

```js
function eliminateDuplicates(arr) {
  var i,
      len = arr.length,
      out = [],
      obj = {};

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    obj[arr[i]] = 0;
  }
  for (i in obj) {
    out.push(i);
  }
  return out;
}

console.log(eliminateDuplicates([1,6,7,3,6,8,1,3,4,5,1,7,2,6]))
```

Source:
http://dreaminginjavascript.wordpress.com/2008/08/22/eliminating-duplicates/

Comment: That is good code, but unfortunately it doesn't do what I'm asking for.

Comment: The code above (which is mine--that's my blog) gets you pretty close. A small tweak and you're there.

First of all, you can see if arr.length and out.length are the same. If they are the same, there are no duplicated elements.

But you want a little more. If you want to "catch" the dupes as they happen, check to see if the length of the array increases after the obj[arr[i]]=0 line. Nifty, eh? :-)

Thanks for the nice words, Raphael Montanaro.

Comment: Also turns Numbers into Strings, which may or may not be acceptable depending on what you're doing. Nice trick however as long as one understands the gotchas

Comment: @MarcoDemaio: Uh, no, why would the code not work with spaces? You can put whatever you like in a property name - just can't use the dot syntax to access ones with spaces (nor props with various other characters which would break parsing).

Comment: @Gijs: +1 you are right. I didn't know it. But it still does not work when it's an array of objects.

Comment: This algorithm also has the side effect of returning a sorted array, which might not be what you want.

Comment: This won't work if you're trying to remove duplicate objects from an array of objects.

Comment: Do you want a *really* elegant way to remove duplicates? Try this one liner: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821/396458

Comment: @asymmetric follow below my answer that returns the duplicates in the same order. att

Comment: as a one-liner, also handling cases were an item occurs more often than twice: arr.slice().sort().filter((e, i, a) => a[i + 1] === e && a[i - 1] !== e)

Comment: @vsync Your assertion is wrong, I can make a single loop slower than two loops.

Comment: @vsync I mean, your assertion is naive. Actually, the time it takes to run an algorithm mainly depends on the size of the input. This answer is O(n), which is not so bad. Read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity.

Answer (score 207):

This is my answer from the duplicate thread (!):

When writing this entry 2014 - all examples were `for`-loops or jQuery. JavaScript has the perfect tools for this: `sort`, `map` and `reduce`.

### Find duplicate items

```js
var names = ['Mike', 'Matt', 'Nancy', 'Adam', 'Jenny', 'Nancy', 'Carl']

const uniq = names
  .map((name) => {
    return {
      count: 1,
      name: name
    };
  })
  .reduce((result, b) => {
    result[b.name] = (result[b.name] || 0) + b.count;

    return result;
  }, {});
const duplicates = Object.keys(uniq).filter((a) => uniq[a] > 1);

console.log(duplicates); // [ 'Nancy' ]
```

### More functional syntax:

@Dmytro-Laptin pointed out some code that can be removed. This is a more compact version of the same code. Using some ES6 tricks and higher-order functions:

```js
const names = ['Mike', 'Matt', 'Nancy', 'Adam', 'Jenny', 'Nancy', 'Carl'];
const count = names =>
  names.reduce((result, value) => ({ ...result,
    [value]: (result[value] || 0) + 1
  }), {}); // don't forget to initialize the accumulator
const duplicates = dict =>
  Object.keys(dict).filter((a) => dict[a] > 1);

console.log(count(names)); // { Mike: 1, Matt: 1, Nancy: 2, Adam: 1, Jenny: 1, Carl: 1 }
console.log(duplicates(count(names))); // [ 'Nancy' ]
```

Comment: @ChristianLandgren, where is 'dict' variable declared? maybe 'count' should be used instead?

Comment: the dict variable is a parameter to the fat-arrow function. It is shorthand for function(dict) { return Object.keys(dict) ... }

Comment: Note that this is not compatible with lower versions of IE due to the `=>` syntax.

Answer (score 164):

UPDATED: *Short* one-liner to get the duplicates:

```js
[1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4].filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) !== i) // [2, 4]
```

To get the array without duplicates simply invert the condition:

```
[1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4].filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) === i) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Note that this answer’s main goal is to be *short*. If you need something *performant* for a big array, one possible solution is to sort your array first (if it is sortable) then do the following to get the same kind of results as above:

```js
myHugeSortedArray.filter((e, i, a) => a[i-1] === e)
```

Here is an example for a 1 000 000 integers array:

```js
const myHugeIntArrayWithDuplicates =
  [...Array(1_000_000).keys()]
  // adding two 0 and four 9 duplicates
  .fill(0, 2, 4).fill(9, 10, 14)

console.time("time")
console.log(
  myHugeIntArrayWithDuplicates
  // a possible sorting method for integers
  .sort((a, b) => a > b ? 1 : -1)
  .filter((e, i, a) => a[i-1] === e)
)
console.timeEnd("time")
```

On my AMD Ryzen 7 5700G dev machine it outputs:

```bash
[ 0, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9 ]
time: 22.738ms
```

As pointed out in the comments both the short solution and the performant solution will return an array with several time the same duplicate if it occurs more than once in the original array:

```js
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2].filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) !== i) // [1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

If unique duplicates are wanted then a function like

```js
function duplicates(arr) {
  return [...new Set(arr.filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) !== i))]
}
```

can be used so that `duplicates([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2])` returns `[1, 2]`.

---

When all you need is to check that there are no duplicates as asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376598/) you can use the `every()` method:

```
[1, 2, 3].every((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) === i) // true

[1, 2, 1].every((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) === i) // false
```

Note that `every()` doesn't work for IE 8 and below.

Comment: Remember: `[2,2,2,2].filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) !== i)` gives `[2, 2, 2]`

Comment: @Wajahath That's true, thanks for pointing that out. If unique duplicates are wanted then a function like `f = arr => [...new Set(arr.filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) !== i))]` can be used so that `f([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2])` returns `[1, 2]`

Comment: performance wise, this is really bad if you have like 1 000 000 entries

Comment: @strix25 that’s true, I added a similar solution that performs much better on a 1 000 000 _sorted_ array.

Answer (score 77):

### Find duplicate values in an array

This should be one of the shortest ways to actually find duplicate values in an array. As specifically asked for by the OP, **this does not remove duplicates but finds them**.

```js
var input = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1];

var duplicates = input.reduce(function(acc, el, i, arr) {
  if (arr.indexOf(el) !== i && acc.indexOf(el) < 0) acc.push(el); return acc;
}, []);

document.write(duplicates); // = 1,3 (actual array == [1, 3])

// Or, using Sets (about 4 times faster)

var duplicates = Array.from(items.reduce((acc, v, i, arr) {
  return arr.indexOf(v) !== i ? acc.add(v) : acc;
}, new Set()))
```

This doesn't need sorting or any third party framework. It also doesn't need manual loops. It works with every value [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (or to be clearer: the [strict comparision operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators)) supports.

Because of [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) it needs at least IE 9.

Comment: ES6 arrow/simple/pure version:
`const dupes = items.reduce((acc, v, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(v) !== i && acc.indexOf(v) === -1 ? acc.concat(v) : acc, [])`

Comment: `if (arr.indexOf(el) !== i && !acc.includes(el) ) acc.push(el); return acc;` works too

Answer (score 31):

You can add this function, or tweak it and add it to Javascript's Array prototype:

```
Array.prototype.unique = function () {
    var r = new Array();
    o:for(var i = 0, n = this.length; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(var x = 0, y = r.length; x < y; x++)
        {
            if(r[x]==this[i])
            {
                alert('this is a DUPE!');
                continue o;
            }
        }
        r[r.length] = this[i];
    }
    return r;
}

var arr = [1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,2,3,7,8,5,9];
var unique = arr.unique();
alert(unique);
```

Comment: This is the best solution, but be careful of adding it to the array prototype, since that will mess up IE if looping through the values.

Comment: @RoyTinker perl supports them too, but I had no idea javascript did

Comment: Does not do what the OP asked for, return the duplicates.

Answer (score 28):

UPDATED: The following uses an optimized combined strategy. It optimizes primitive lookups to benefit from hash O(1) lookup time (running `unique` on an array of primitives is O(n)). Object lookups are optimized by tagging objects with a unique id while iterating through so so identifying duplicate objects is also O(1) per item and O(n) for the whole list. The only exception is items that are frozen, but those are rare and a fallback is provided using an array and indexOf.

```
var unique = function(){
  var hasOwn = {}.hasOwnProperty,
      toString = {}.toString,
      uids = {};

  function uid(){
    var key = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
    return key in uids ? uid() : uids[key] = key;
  }

  function unique(array){
    var strings = {}, numbers = {}, others = {},
        tagged = [], failed = [],
        count = 0, i = array.length,
        item, type;

    var id = uid();

    while (i--) {
      item = array[i];
      type = typeof item;
      if (item == null || type !== 'object' && type !== 'function') {
        // primitive
        switch (type) {
          case 'string': strings[item] = true; break;
          case 'number': numbers[item] = true; break;
          default: others[item] = item; break;
        }
      } else {
        // object
        if (!hasOwn.call(item, id)) {
          try {
            item[id] = true;
            tagged[count++] = item;
          } catch (e){
            if (failed.indexOf(item) === -1)
              failed[failed.length] = item;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // remove the tags
    while (count--)
      delete tagged[count][id];

    tagged = tagged.concat(failed);
    count = tagged.length;

    // append primitives to results
    for (i in strings)
      if (hasOwn.call(strings, i))
        tagged[count++] = i;

    for (i in numbers)
      if (hasOwn.call(numbers, i))
        tagged[count++] = +i;

    for (i in others)
      if (hasOwn.call(others, i))
        tagged[count++] = others[i];

    return tagged;
  }

  return unique;
}();
```

If you have ES6 Collections available, then there is a much simpler and significantly faster version. (shim for IE9+ and other browsers here: https://github.com/Benvie/ES6-Harmony-Collections-Shim)

```
function unique(array){
  var seen = new Set;
  return array.filter(function(item){
    if (!seen.has(item)) {
      seen.add(item);
      return true;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: really? why answer a question which has been solved over 2 years ago?

Comment: I was answering another question and apparently accidentally clicked on someone linking to this one, calling it a duplicate, and ended up cloning my answer and confusing the hell out of myself. I edit my stuff a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683845/removing-duplicates-from-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: I think it's nice with different solutions. It doesn't matter that the topic is old and solved since it's still possible to come up with different ways of doing this. It's a typical problem in computer science.

Comment: You might want to mention that this relies on ES5 Array methods that aren't implemented in IE < 9.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple counter for the `uid` function?

Answer (score 24):

```
var a = ["a","a","b","c","c"];

a.filter(function(value,index,self){ return (self.indexOf(value) !== index )})
```

Comment: This seems to work, but you should probably include some text describing how it works.

Comment: Won't work if there are more 2 occurrences of a duplicate value.

Comment: This is elegant and simple. I love it. For those wanting to figure out how they work, I've created a gist showing how to show duplicates and eliminate duplicates. See here: https://gist.github.com/jbcoder/f1c616a32ee4d642691792eebdc4257b

Comment: @TheDIMMReaper for the second `'a'` in array, inside filter function the `index == 1`, whereas `self.indexOf('a') == 0`

Answer (score 23):

This should get you what you want, Just the duplicates.

```
function find_duplicates(arr) {
  var len=arr.length,
      out=[],
      counts={};

  for (var i=0;i<len;i++) {
    var item = arr[i];
    counts[item] = counts[item] >= 1 ? counts[item] + 1 : 1;
    if (counts[item] === 2) {
      out.push(item);
    }
  }

  return out;
}

find_duplicates(['one',2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,7,7,'pig','one']); // -> ['one',4,7] in no particular order.
```

Answer (score 23):

## Find *non-unique* values from 3 arrays (or more):

### ES2015

```js
//                             
var arr =  [1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,2,3,7,8,5,22],
    arr2 = [1,2,511,12,50],
    arr3 = [22,0],
    merged,
    nonUnique;

// Combine all the arrays to a single one
merged = arr.concat(arr2, arr3)

// create a new (dirty) Array with only the non-unique items
nonUnique = merged.filter((item,i) => merged.includes(item, i+1))

// Cleanup - remove duplicate & empty items items 
nonUnique = [...new Set(nonUnique)]

console.log(nonUnique)
```

---

### PRE-ES2015:

In the below example I chose to superimpose a `unique` method on top of the `Array` *prototype*, allowing access from everywhere and has more *"declarative"* syntax. I do not recommend this approach on large projects, since it might very well collide with another method with the same custom name.

```js
Array.prototype.unique = function () {
    var arr = this.sort(), i=arr.length; // input must be sorted for this to work
    while(i--)
      arr[i] === arr[i-1] && arr.splice(i,1) // remove duplicate item
    return arr
}

Array.prototype.nonunique = function () {
    var arr = this.sort(), i=arr.length, res = []; // input must be sorted for this to work
    while(i--)
      arr[i] === arr[i-1] && (res.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1) && res.push(arr[i]) 
    return res
}

//                             
var arr =  [1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,2,3,7,8,5,22],
    arr2 = [1,2,511,12,50],
    arr3 = [22,0],
    // merge all arrays & call custom Array Prototype - "unique"
    unique = arr.concat(arr2, arr3).unique(),
    nonunique = arr.concat(arr2, arr3).nonunique()

console.log(unique)     // [1,12,2,22,3,4,5,50,511,6,7,8]
console.log(nonunique)  // [1,12,2,22,3,4,5,50,511,6,7,8]
```

Comment: +1 because it's definitely more readable the code using Array.indexOf, but unfortunately it seems slower than using a simple nested loop. Even on browsers that implements Array.indexOf nayively like FF. Plz, Have a look at these tests I did here: http://jsperf.com/array-unique2 and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @shekhardesigner - updated answer. "r" is the array you search in

Comment: @vsync I had to initialize, `var r = [];` to get your code working. And worked like charm.

Comment: @shekhardesigner - I'm sorry for the mix, for the Array Prototype solution you don't need an `r` variable

Comment: Does not do what the OP asked for, return the duplicates.

Comment: @RWC - it appears so. I will update the answer in the coming days to best suit the OP's question

Comment: I had to change `this.sort()` to `this.slice().sort()` for the PRE-ES2015 one to not affect the orginal array. Otherwise good answer.

Answer (score 15):

The simplest and quickest way is to use the `Set` object:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6];

const set = new Set(numbers);

const duplicates = numbers.filter(item => {
    if (set.has(item)) {
        set.delete(item);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});

// OR more concisely

const duplicates = numbers.filter(item => !set.delete(item));

console.log(duplicates);
// [ 2, 5 ]
```

Comment: Good clear algorithm.  By the way, this reports triplicate elements twice, which may well be desirable.

Comment: An improvement on this would be `item => !set.delete(item)`, as Set.delete() return false if the item was not in the set.

Comment: @nebkat Set.delete() returns false if the item was not in the array and true if it was. We want the opposite of that, so we invert it. That makes sense. It just feels a little confusing to read the concise version because two things are happening: it's checking for the item in the set, and deleting the item from the set. I'm just asking for clarification really, thank you.

Answer (score 14):

using underscore.js

```
function hasDuplicate(arr){
    return (arr.length != _.uniq(arr).length);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

This is my proposal (ES6):

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1, 5, 6]
let b = [...new Set(a.sort().filter((o, i) => o !== undefined && a[i + 1] !== undefined && o === a[i + 1]))]

// b is now [1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: This will report that a single occurrence of `undefined` is a duplicate.

Comment: updated solution based on the comment (forgot to mention it earlier)

Answer (score 9):

Here's the simplest solution I could think of:

```js
const arr = [-1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 500, -1, 'a', 'a', 'a']

const filtered = arr.filter((el, index) => arr.indexOf(el) !== index)
// => filtered = [ 2, 2, 0, 0, -1, 'a', 'a' ]

const duplicates = [...new Set(filtered)]

console.log(duplicates)
// => [ 2, 0, -1, 'a' ]
```

That's it.

**Note:**

1. It works with any numbers including `0`, strings and negative numbers e.g. `-1` -
   **Related question:**  [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473)
2. The original array `arr` is preserved (`filter` returns the new array instead of modifying the original)
3. The `filtered` array contains **all** duplicates; it **can** also contain more than 1 same value (e.g. our filtered array here is `[ 2, 2, 0, 0, -1, 'a', 'a' ]`)
4. If you want to get **only** values that are duplicated (you don't want to have multiple duplicates with the same value) you can use `[...new Set(filtered)]` (ES6 has an object **Set** which can store only unique values)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

Here is mine simple and one line solution.

It searches not unique elements first, then makes found array unique with the use of Set.

So we have array of duplicates in the end.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 7, 8, 5, 22, 1, 2, 511, 12, 50, 22];

console.log([...new Set(
  array.filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) !== index))]
);
```

Answer (score 7):

one liner simple way

```js
var arr = [9,1,2,4,3,4,9]
console.log(arr.filter((ele,indx)=>indx!==arr.indexOf(ele))) //get the duplicates
console.log(arr.filter((ele,indx)=>indx===arr.indexOf(ele))) //remove the duplicates
```

Comment: what does `indx!` do for the first example?

Comment: @saylestyler Hehe, this means `indx !== ...` - strict inequality.

Comment: only adding for array of objects `result.filter((ele,indx) => indx !== result.map(e => e.name).indexOf(ele.name));`

Answer (score 7):

**Shortest vanilla JS**:

```
[1,1,2,2,2,3].filter((v,i,a) => a.indexOf(v) !== i) // [1, 2, 2]
```

Comment: and if you need result without duplication `new Set(result)` will get rid of them

Comment: I like this solution sooo much!

Answer (score 6):

```
var a = [324,3,32,5,52,2100,1,20,2,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1].sort();
a.filter(function(v,i,o){return i&&v!==o[i-1]?v:0;});
```

or when added to the prototyp.chain of Array

```
//copy and paste: without error handling
Array.prototype.unique = 
   function(){return this.sort().filter(function(v,i,o){return i&&v!==o[i-1]?v:0;});}
```

See here: https://gist.github.com/1305056

Comment: The filter function should return true or false, not the element itself. Filtering an array containing 0's would not have returned them.

Comment: Also, I assume the `i&&` is for avoiding going out of bounds of the array, but it also means that the first element in the sorted array will not be included. In your example there is no `1` in the resulting array.

I.e. `return i&&v!==o[i-1]?v:0;` should be `return v!==o[i-1];`

Answer (score 6):

**Fast and elegant way using es6 object destructuring and reduce**

It runs in O(n) (1 iteration over the array) and doesn't repeat values that appear more than 2 times

```js
const arr = ['hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'bye', 'bye', 'asd']
const {
  dup
} = arr.reduce(
  (acc, curr) => {
    acc.items[curr] = acc.items[curr] ? acc.items[curr] += 1 : 1
    if (acc.items[curr] === 2) acc.dup.push(curr)
    return acc
  }, {
    items: {},
    dup: []
  },
)

console.log(dup)
// ['hi', 'bye']
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use filter method and indexOf() to get all the duplicate values

```
function duplicate(arr) {
    return duplicateArray = arr.filter((item, index) => arr.indexOf(item) !== index) 
}
```

**arr.indexOf(item)** will always return the first index at which a given element can be
found

Answer (score 4):

The following function (a variation of the eliminateDuplicates function already mentioned) seems to do the trick, returning test2,1,7,5 for the input ["test", "test2", "test2", 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 10, 22, 43, 1, 5, 8]

Note that the problem is stranger in JavaScript than in most other languages, because a JavaScript array can hold just about anything. Note that solutions that use sorting might need to provide an appropriate sorting function--I haven't tried that route yet.

This particular implementation works for (at least) strings and numbers.

```
function findDuplicates(arr) {
    var i,
        len=arr.length,
        out=[],
        obj={};

    for (i=0;i<len;i++) {
        if (obj[arr[i]] != null) {
            if (!obj[arr[i]]) {
                out.push(arr[i]);
                obj[arr[i]] = 1;
            }
        } else {
            obj[arr[i]] = 0;            
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

ES5 only (i.e., it needs a filter() polyfill for IE8 and below):

```
var arrayToFilter = [ 4, 5, 5, 5, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3 ];

arrayToFilter.
    sort().
    filter( function(me,i,arr){
       return (i===0) || ( me !== arr[i-1] );
    });
```

Comment: I like this simple solution.  If you want the duplicates, though, you need to first find those duplicates, and then make the duplicate list unique.  [ 0, 4, 5, 5, 5, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3 ].sort().filter( function(me,i,arr){ return (i!==0) && ( me == arr[i-1] ); }).filter( function(me,i,arr){ return (i===0) || ( me !== arr[i-1] ); });

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very light and easy way:

```
var codes = dc_1.split(',');
var i = codes.length;
while (i--) {
  if (codes.indexOf(codes[i]) != i) {
    codes.splice(i,1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Best answer. And if user want duplicate elements array , for this i updated @brandon code


var i = codes .length;
var duplicate = [];
while (i--) {
  if (codes .indexOf(codes [i]) != i) {
if(duplicate.indexOf(codes [i]) === -1){
      duplicate.push(arr[i]);  
}
codes.splice(i,1);
  }
}

Answer (score 4):

ES6 offers the Set data structure which is basically an array that doesn't accept duplicates.
With the Set data structure, there's a very easy way to find duplicates in an array (using only one loop).

Here's my code

```
function findDuplicate(arr) {
var set = new Set();
var duplicates = new Set();
  for (let i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
     var size = set.size;
     set.add(arr[i]);
     if (set.size === size) {
         duplicates.add(arr[i]);
     }
  }
 return duplicates;
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution. I'm surprised it hasn't received more upvotes!

Answer (score 4):

With ES6 (or using Babel or Typescipt) you can simply do:

```
var duplicates = myArray.filter(i => myArray.filter(ii => ii === i).length > 1);
```

https://es6console.com/j58euhbt/

Comment: I came to the same syntax, independently, and was just about to add it as a solution when I found this one. It probably isn't the most economical, but it is simple.

Answer (score 4):

I have just figured out a simple way to achieve this using an Array filter

```js
    var list = [9, 9, 111, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7];
    
    // Filter 1: to find all duplicates elements
    var duplicates = list.filter(function(value,index,self) {
       return self.indexOf(value) !== self.lastIndexOf(value) && self.indexOf(value) === index;
    });
    
    console.log(duplicates);
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple code with ES6 syntax (return sorted array of duplicates):

```
let duplicates = a => {d=[]; a.sort((a,b) => a-b).reduce((a,b)=>{a==b&&!d.includes(a)&&d.push(a); return b}); return d};
```

How to use:

```
duplicates([1,2,3,10,10,2,3,3,10]);
```

Comment: .filter() would be much simpler

Answer (score 4):

This answer might also be helpful, it leverages js `reduce` **operator/method** to remove **duplicates** from array.

```js
const result = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3].reduce((x, y) => x.includes(y) ? x : [...x, y], []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: we can now just do `new Set([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3])` to remove duplicates

Answer (score 4):

Higher ranked answers have a few inherent issues including the use of legacy javascript, incorrect ordering or with only support for 2 duplicated items.

Here's a modern solution which fixes those problems:

```js
const arrayNonUniq = array => {
    if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
        throw new TypeError("An array must be provided!")
    }

    return array.filter((value, index) => array.indexOf(value) === index && array.lastIndexOf(value) !== index)
}

arrayNonUniq([1, 1, 2, 3, 3])
//=> [1, 3]

arrayNonUniq(["foo", "foo", "bar", "foo"])
//=> ['foo']
```

You can also use the npm package [`array-non-uniq`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-non-uniq).

Answer (score 3):

```js
var arr = [2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 5];

function returnDuplicates(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(dupes, val, i) {
    if (arr.indexOf(val) !== i && dupes.indexOf(val) === -1) {
      dupes.push(val);
    }
    return dupes;
  }, []);
}

alert(returnDuplicates(arr));
```

This function **avoids the sorting step** and uses the reduce() method to push duplicates to a new array if it doesn't already exist in it.

Answer (score 3):

Using "includes" to test if the element already exists.

```js
var arr = [1, 1, 4, 5, 5], darr = [], duplicates = [];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  if(darr.includes(arr[i]) && !duplicates.includes(arr[i]))
    duplicates.push(arr[i])
  else
    darr.push(arr[i]);
}

console.log(duplicates);
```

```html
<h3>Array with duplicates</h3>
<p>[1, 1, 4, 5, 5]</p>
<h3>Array with distinct elements</h3>
<p>[1, 4, 5]</p>
<h3>duplicate values are</h3>
<p>[1, 5]</p>
```

Comment: The code does give back distinct elements, but does not lead to the given result. Please provide complete correct code .

Answer (score 3):

**Following logic will be easier and faster**

```
// @Param:data:Array that is the source 
// @Return : Array that have the duplicate entries
findDuplicates(data: Array<any>): Array<any> {
        return Array.from(new Set(data)).filter((value) => data.indexOf(value) !== data.lastIndexOf(value));
      }
```

**Advantages :**

1. Single line :-P
2. All inbuilt data structure helping in improving the efficiency
3. Faster

**Description of Logic  :**

1. Converting to set to remove all duplicates
2. Iterating through the set values
3. With each set value check in the source array for the condition "values first index is not equal to the last index" == > Then inferred as duplicate else it is 'unique'

**Note:** map() and filter() methods are efficient and faster.

Comment: Tested this... very fast. and it makes sense.. wish i thought about it

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the function way of doing this.

```
function removeDuplicates(links) {
    return _.reduce(links, function(list, elem) { 
        if (list.indexOf(elem) == -1) {
            list.push(elem);
        }   
        return list;
    }, []);
}
```

This uses underscore, but Array has a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function, too

Comment: Does not do what the OP asked for, return the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c'],
    duplicates = [],
    i, j;
for (i = 0, j = input.length; i < j; i++) {
  if (duplicates.indexOf(input[i]) === -1 && input.indexOf(input[i], i+1) !== -1) {
    duplicates.push(input[i]);
  }
}

console.log(duplicates);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the below is the easiest and fastest O(n) way to accomplish exactly what you asked:

```
function getDuplicates( arr ) {
  var i, value;
  var all = {};
  var duplicates = [];

  for( i=0; i<arr.length; i++ ) {
    value = arr[i];
    if( all[value] ) {
      duplicates.push( value );
      all[value] = false;
    } else if( typeof all[value] == "undefined" ) {
      all[value] = true;
    }
  }

  return duplicates;
}
```

Or for ES5 or greater:

```
function getDuplicates( arr ) {
  var all = {};
  return arr.reduce(function( duplicates, value ) {
    if( all[value] ) {
      duplicates.push(value);
      all[value] = false;
    } else if( typeof all[value] == "undefined" ) {
      all[value] = true;
    }
    return duplicates;
  }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Modifying @RaphaelMontanaro's solution, borrowing from @Nosredna's blog, here is what you could do if you just want to identify the duplicate elements from your array.

```
function identifyDuplicatesFromArray(arr) {
        var i;
        var len = arr.length;
        var obj = {};
        var duplicates = [];

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

            if (!obj[arr[i]]) {

                obj[arr[i]] = {};

            }

            else
            {
                duplicates.push(arr[i]);
            }

        }
        return duplicates;
    }
```

Thanks for the elegant solution, @Nosredna!

Answer (score 2):

I did not like most answers.

Why? Too complicated, too much code, inefficient code and many do not answer the question, which is to find the duplicates (and not to give an array without the duplicates).

Next function returns all duplicates:

```
function GetDuplicates(arr) {
  var i, out=[], obj={};
  for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    obj[arr[i]] == undefined ? obj[arr[i]] ++ : out.push(arr[i]);
  return out;
}
```

Because most of the time it is of no use to return ALL duplicates, but just to tell which duplicate values exist. In that case you return an array with unique duplicates ;-)

```
function GetDuplicates(arr) {
  var i, out=[], obj={};
  for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
    obj[arr[i]] == undefined ? obj[arr[i]] ++ : out.push(arr[i]);
  return GetUnique(out);
}

function GetUnique(arr) {
  return $.grep(arr, function(elem, index) {
    return index == $.inArray(elem, arr);
  });
}
```

Maybe somebody else thinks the same.

Answer (score 2):

**This is probably one of the fastest way to remove permanently the duplicates from an array**
10x times faster than the most functions here.& 78x faster in safari

```
function toUnique(a,b,c){//array,placeholder,placeholder
 b=a.length;
 while(c=--b)while(c--)a[b]!==a[c]||a.splice(c,1)
}
var array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,1];
toUnique(array);
console.log(array);
```

1. Test: http://jsperf.com/wgu
2. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/46S7g/
3. More: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25082874/2450730

if you can't read the code above ask, read a javascript book or here are some explainations about shorter code. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21353032/2450730

**EDIT**
As stated in the comments this function does return an array with uniques, the question however asks to find the duplicates. in that case a simple modification to this function allows to push the duplicates into an array, then using the previous function `toUnique` removes the duplicates of the duplicates.

```
function theDuplicates(a,b,c,d){//array,placeholder,placeholder
 b=a.length,d=[];
 while(c=--b)while(c--)a[b]!==a[c]||d.push(a.splice(c,1))
}
var array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,1];

toUnique(theDuplicates(array));
```

Comment: "if you can't read the code above ask, read a javascript book" There's entirely too much code golf in this answer.  Naming the variables things like a, b, c makes the code difficult to read.  Forgoing curly braces makes it even worse.

Comment: Most of my answers are based on performance and space savings (other solutions are already posted)... if you don't like it downvote ... else learn javascript, read a js book... or use jquery... they have alot more answers if you search a simple solution. If you really want to learn something i'm happy to explain the code letter per letter. As i can't see a real question in your comment i guess you are just searching for a motive to downvote my answer .... go on... i have no problem with that. Ask a real question or tell me something that does not work with my code.

Comment: There is nothing technically wrong with your code.  That said, naming variables a, b, c, d, etc. and chaining while loops makes the code difficult to read.  So, the code fails to teach anything.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong... But I'm pretty sure the JavaScript interpreter doesn't keep variable names as is. Minifying code like this shouldn't have any effect on the **efficiency** of the code. Yes, it'll result in a smaller amount of **bandwidth** being consumed, but including curly braces, or `reallyLongVariableNamesJustForTheSakeOfIt` shouldn't effect performance at all... Also, making statements like, `read a javascript book` just comes across as obnoxious and, quite frankly, rude.

Answer (score 2):

To solve the above in O(n) time complexity (without sorting).

```
var arr = [9, 9, 111, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7];

var obj={};

for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(!obj[arr[i]]){
        obj[arr[i]]=1;
    } else {
        obj[arr[i]]=obj[arr[i]]+1;
    }
}
var result=[]
for(var key in obj){
    if(obj[key]>1){
        result.push(Number(key)) // change this to result.push(key) to find duplicate strings in an array
    }
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function GetDuplicates(arr) {
    var i = 0, m = [];
    return arr.filter(function (n) {
        return !m[n] * ~arr.indexOf(n, m[n] = ++i);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel like the simplest solution would to just use indexOf

full example of pushing only unique elements to an array.

```
var arr = ['a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d'];
var newA = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(newA.indexOf(arr[i]) === -1){
        newA.push(arr[i]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Does not do what the OP asked for, return the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

There is a really simple way to solve this.  If you use the newish 'Set' javascript command.  Set can take an array as input and output a new 'Set' that only contains unique values.  Then by comparing the length of the array and the 'size' property of the set you can see if they differ.  If they differ it must be due to a duplicate entry.

```js
var array1 = ['value1','value2','value3','value1']; // contains duplicates
var array2 = ['value1','value2','value3','value4']; // unique values

console.log('array1 contains duplicates = ' + containsDuplicates(array1));
console.log('array2 contains duplicates = ' + containsDuplicates(array2));


function containsDuplicates(passedArray) {
  let mySet = new Set(passedArray);
  if (mySet.size !== passedArray.length) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

If you run the above snippet you will get this output.

array1 contains duplicates = true

array2 contains duplicates = false

Answer (score 2):

There are so many answers already, but unfortunately some are too long, some are short but too cryptic for me while others are beyond my scope of knowledge... I really like this solution that I've come up with, though. Hope it's still helpful for some!

Even though the original post says he/she doesn't actually need the duplicates' indexes or how many times they are duplicated, I think it's still clearest to have 'em counted.

Codes with notes.

```
function findDuplicates(array, count = {}) {
  // with count declared in the parameter, initialized as an empty object, 
  // it can store the counts of all elements in array  
  
  // using the forEach loop to iterate through the input array, 
  // also using the conditional ternary operators 
  // (works just like a normal if-else statement, but just a bit cleaner)
  // we can store all occurrences of each element from array in count
  array.forEach(el => count[el] ? count[el]++ : count[el] = 1)
  
  // using Object.keys, we get an array of all keys from count (all numbers) 
  // (sorted as well, though of no specific importance here)
  // using filter to find all elements with a count (value) > 1 (duplicates!)
  return Object.keys(count).filter(key => count[key] > 1);
}
```

Just the codes (with test cases).

```js
function findDuplicates(array, count = {}) {
  array.forEach(el => count[el] ? count[el]++ : count[el] = 1);
  return Object.keys(count).filter(key => count[key] > 1);
}

let arr1 = [9, 9, 111, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7];
let arr2 = [1,6,7,3,6,8,1,3,4,5,1,7,2,6];
console.log(findDuplicates(arr1)); // => ['4', '9']
console.log(findDuplicates(arr2)); // => ['1', '3', '6', '7']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some theory to the above.

Finding duplicates has a lower bound of O(n*log(n) in the comparison model.  SO theoretically, you cannot do any better than first sorting then going through the
list sequentially removing any duplicates you find.

If you want to find the duplicates in linear (O(n))  *expected* time, you could
hash each element of the list; if there is a collision, remove/label it as a duplicate,
and continue.

Comment: Agreed. The only reason to try different approaches here is that the speed depends on how well various things are implemented in the runtime. And that's going to vary browser-to-browser. For short lists, it probably doesn't matter much how you solve the problem. For large arrays, it does.

Answer (score 1):

/*
The indexOf method of the Array object is useful for comparing array items.
IE is the only major browser that does not natively support it, but it is easy to implement:
*/

```
Array.prototype.indexOf= Array.prototype.indexOf || function(what, i){
    i= i || 0;
    var L= this.length;
    while(i<L){
        if(this[i]=== what) return i;
        ++i;
    }
    return -1;
}

function getarrayduplicates(arg){
    var itm, A= arg.slice(0, arg.length), dups= [];
    while(A.length){
        itm= A.shift();
        if(A.indexOf(itm)!= -1 && dups.indexOf(itm)== -1){
            dups[dups.length]= itm;
        }
    }
    return dups;
}
```

var a1= [1, 22, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 22, 7, 8, 9];

alert(getarrayduplicates(a1));

For very large arrays, it can be faster to remove the duplicates from the array as they are found, so that they will not be looked at again:

```
function getarrayduplicates(arg){
    var itm, A= arg.slice(0, arg.length), dups= [];
    while(A.length){
        itm= A.shift();
        if(A.indexOf(itm)!= -1){
            dups[dups.length]= itm;
            while(A.indexOf(itm)!= -1){
                A.splice(A.indexOf(itm), 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return dups;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/gfJ28/

```
var arr  = ['hello','goodbye','foo','hello','foo','bar',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3];
var hash = [];

// build hash
for (var n=arr.length; n--; ){
   if (typeof hash[arr[n]] === 'undefined') hash[arr[n]] = [];
   hash[arr[n]].push(n);
}


// work with compiled hash (not necessary)
var duplicates = [];
for (var key in hash){
    if (hash.hasOwnProperty(key) && hash[key].length > 1){
        duplicates.push(key);
    }
}    
alert(duplicates);
```

1. The result will be the `hash` array, which will contain both a unique set of values and the position of those values.  So if there are 2 or more positions, we can determine that the value has a duplicate.  Thus, every place `hash[<value>].length > 1`, signifies a duplicate.
2. `hash['hello']` will return `[0,3]` because 'hello' was found in node 0 and 3 in `arr[]`.

   ***Note:** the length of `[0,3]` is what's used to determine if it was a duplicate.*
3. Using `for(var key in hash){ if (hash.hasOwnProperty(key)){ alert(key); } }` will alert each unique value.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way by using underscore. Numbers is the source array and dupes has possible duplicate values.

```
var itemcounts = _.countBy(numbers, function (n) { return n; });
var dupes = _.reduce(itemcounts, function (memo, item, idx) {
    if (item > 1)
        memo.push(idx);
    return memo;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to a few other answers, but I used [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to make it a bit prettier:

```
function find_duplicates(data) {

    var track = {};
    var duplicates = [];

    data.forEach(function (item) {
        !track[item] ? track[item] = true : duplicates.push(item);
    });

    return duplicates;
}
```

If a value is duplicated more than once, all its duplicates are returned, like so:

```
find_duplicates(['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar']);
// returns ['foo', 'bar', 'bar']
```

This might be what you want, otherwise you just have to follow with an "unique" filtering.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to solve is is actually with a flag

```js
var values = [4,2,3,1,4]

// solution
const checkDuplicate = list => {
  var hasDuplicate = false;
  list.sort().sort((a, b) => {
    if (a === b) hasDuplicate = true
  })
  return hasDuplicate
}

console.log(checkDuplicate(values))
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be solved using `Set()`.

**A value in the Set may only occur once;** it is unique in the Set's collection.

```
    Array.prototype.hasDuplicates = function () {
        if (arr.length !== (new Set(arr).size)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

More information on Sets:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

***Note:*** Sets are not fully supported in IE.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the simple ES5 solution I could think of -

```
function duplicates(arr) {
  var duplicatesArr = [],
      uniqueObj = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if( uniqueObj.hasOwnProperty(arr[i]) && duplicatesArr.indexOf( arr[i] ) === -1) {
      duplicatesArr.push( arr[i] );
    }
    else {
      uniqueObj[ arr[i] ] = true;
    }
  }

  return duplicatesArr;
}
/* Input Arr: [1,1,2,2,2,1,3,4,5,3] */
/* OutPut Arr: [1,2,3] */
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//find duplicates:
//sort, then reduce - concat values equal previous element, skip others

//input
var a = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2]

//short version:
var duplicates = a.sort().reduce((d, v, i, a) => i && v === a[i - 1] ? d.concat(v) : d, [])
console.log(duplicates); //[1, 1, 2, 2]

//readable version:
var duplicates = a.sort().reduce((output, element, index, input) => {
  if ((index > 0) && (element === input[index - 1]))
    return output.concat(element)
  return output
}, [])
console.log(duplicates); //[1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @whossname may be we should add snippet with more self-explanatory variable names

Comment: @AfanasiiKurakin I think it would also help to use an if statement instead of the ternary operator

Answer (score 1):

1. Printing duplicate values

```js
 var arr = [1,2,3,4,13,2,3,4,3,4];

    // non_unique Printing 
    function nonUnique(arr){
    var result = [];
    for(var i =0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr.indexOf(arr[i],i+1) > -1){
            result.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(result);
    }nonUnique(arr);

    // unique Printing
    function uniqueDuplicateVal(arr){
       var result = [];
       for(var i =0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr.indexOf(arr[i],i+1) > -1){
          if(result.indexOf(arr[i]) === -1]){
             result.push(arr[i]);
          }
        }
       }    
    }
    uniqueDuplicateVal(arr)
```

Comment: "nonUnique" seems to work, but I'm not sure why. What are you offsetting the start index by the index in the for loop for indexOf?

Answer (score 1):

This should be one of the shortest and easiest ways to actually find duplicate values in an array.

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,3,3,4];
var data = arr.filter(function(item,index,arr){
  return arr.indexOf(item) != arr.lastIndexOf(item) && arr.indexOf(item) == index;
})

console.log(data );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is most efficient way i can think of as doesn't include `Array.indexOf()` or `Array.lastIndexOf()` which have complexity of O(n) and using inside any loop of complexity O(n) will make complete complexity O(n^2).

My first loop have complexity of O(n/2) or O((n/2) + 1), as complexity of search in hash is O(1). The second loop worst complexity when there's no duplicate in array is O(n) and best complexity when every element have a duplicate is O(n/2).

```
function duplicates(arr) {
  let duplicates = [],
      d = {},
      i = 0,
      j = arr.length - 1;

  // Complexity O(n/2)
  while (i <= j) {
    if (i === j)
      d[arr[i]] ? d[arr[i]] += 1 : d[arr[i]] = 1;  // Complexity O(1)
    else {
      d[arr[i]] ? d[arr[i]] += 1 : d[arr[i]] = 1;  // Complexity O(1)
      d[arr[j]] ? d[arr[j]] += 1 : d[arr[j]] = 1;  // Complexity O(1)
    }

    ++i;
    --j;
  }

  // Worst complexity O(n), best complexity O(n/2)
  for (let k in d) {
    if (d[k] > 1)
      duplicates.push(k);
  }

  return duplicates;

}

console.log(duplicates([5,6,4,9,2,3,5,3,4,1,5,4,9]));
console.log(duplicates([2,3,4,5,4,3,4]));
console.log(duplicates([4,5,2,9]));
console.log(duplicates([4,5,2,9,2,5,9,4]));
```

Answer (score 1):

### Magic

```
a.filter(( t={}, e=>!(1-(t[e]=++t[e]|0)) ))
```

**O(n) performance**; we assume your array is in `a` and it contains elements that can be cast `.toString()` in unique way (which is done implicity by JS in `t[e]`)   e.g numbers=[4,5,4], strings=["aa","bb","aa"], arraysNum=[[1,2,3], [43,2,3],[1,2,3]]. Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53453045/860099), unique values [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53526999/860099)

```js
var a1 = [[2, 17], [2, 17], [2, 17], [1, 12], [5, 9], [1, 12], [6, 2], [1, 12]];
var a2 = ['Mike', 'Adam','Matt', 'Nancy', 'Adam', 'Jenny', 'Nancy', 'Carl'];
var a3 = [5,6,4,9,2,3,5,3,4,1,5,4,9];

let nd = (a) => a.filter((t={},e=>!(1-(t[e]=++t[e]|0)))) 


// Print
let c= x => console.log(JSON.stringify(x));             
c( nd(a1) );
c( nd(a2) );
c( nd(a3) );
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a single loop approach with a hash table for counting the elements and filter the array if the count is `2`, because it returns the first found duplicate.

Advantage:

- single loop
- uses an object for counting in a closure

```js
var array = [5, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 8, 6, 7, 9, 4],
    duplicates = array.filter((h => v => (h[v] = (h[v] || 0) + 1) === 2)({}));
    
console.log(duplicates);
```

Comment: Can we get duplicate values as well as their occurrence like `[2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]` ?

Comment: @meteorzeroo that is a different question, but in this case you need in advance to know if the count is is greater than one. that means, you need at lest two pass.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `sort`, `filter` and `sets` to do that.

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,3,3,4];
var numbersSorted = numbers.sort();
let result = numbers.filter((e, i) => numbers[i] == numbers[i+1]);
result = [...new Set(result)];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @bluemoon but shorter, returns all duplicates exactly once!

```js
function checkDuplicateKeys(arr) {
    const counts = {}
    return arr.filter((item) => {
        counts[item] = counts[item] || 1
        if (counts[item]++ === 2) return true
    })
}

// [1,2,2,2,2,2,2] => [1,2]
// ['dog', 'dog', 'cat'] => ['dog']
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const names = [
  "Alex",
  "Matt",
  12,
  "You",
  "Me",
  12,
  "Carol",
  "Bike",
  "Carol",
];

const count = (names) =>
  names.reduce((a, b) => ({ ...a, [b]: (a[b] || 0) + 1 }), {});

let obj = count(names);
let objectKeys = Object.keys(obj);

let repetitiveElements = [];
let answer = objectKeys.map((value) => {
  if (obj[value] > 1) {
    return repetitiveElements.push(value);
  }
});
console.log(repetitiveElements);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a shame that this question has so many wrong answers or answers which need a lot of extra memory like a Set. Clean and simple solution:

```
function findDuplicates<T>(arr: Array<T>): T[] {
  //If the array has less than 2 elements there are no duplicates
  const n = arr.length;
  if (n < 2)
    return [];
  
  const sorted = arr.sort();
  const result = [];

  //Head
  if (sorted[0] === sorted[1])
    result.push(sorted[0]);

  //Inner (Head :: Inner :: Tail)
  for (let i = 1; i < n-1; i++) {
    const elem = sorted[i];
    if (elem === sorted[i - 1] || elem === sorted[i+1])
      result.push(elem)
  }

  //Tail
  if (sorted[n - 1] == sorted[n - 2])
    result.push(sorted[n - 1]);

  return result;
}

console.dir(findDuplicates(['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']));
console.dir(findDuplicates(['a', 'b']));
console.dir(findDuplicates(['a', 'a', 'a']));
console.dir(findDuplicates(['a']));
console.dir(findDuplicates([]));
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way to remove duplicates is by using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const remove = (array) => [...new Set(array)];
console.log(remove([1,1,2,2,3]); //1,2,3
```

Comment: This doesn't fully answer the original question but it was very helpful. I [expanded on your method](https://jsfiddle.net/d173yLjs/1/) to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

**this is the simplest way to find the duplicated elements with ES6 syntax**

```js
const arr =[1,2,3,3,21,3, 21,34]
const duplicates = Array.from(new Set(arr.filter((eg, i, ar)=> i !==ar.indexOf(eg))))
console.log(duplicates)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this, you will get elements that are unique and element that are repeating in two different arrays.

Complexity O(n)

```js
let start = [1,1,2,1,3,4,5,6,5,5];
start.sort();
const unique=[];
const repeat = [];
let ii=-1 ; 
for(let i =0 ; i<start.length; i++){
    if(start[i]===start[i-1]){
      if(repeat[ii]!==start[i-1]){
        repeat.push(start[i-1]);
        ii++;
      }
    }
    else {
        if(i+1<start.length){
          if(start[i]!==start[i+1]){
            unique.push(start[i]);
          }
        }
        else if(i===start.length-1){
          unique.push(start[i]);
        }
    }
}
console.log(unique) ; 
console.log(repeat);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Prototype library has a [uniq](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/array/uniq) function, which returns the array without the dupes. That's only half of the work though.

Answer (score 0):

From Raphael Montanaro answer, it can improve to use with array/object item as follows.

```
function eliminateDuplicates(arr) {
  var len = arr.length,
      out = [],
      obj = {};

  for (var key, i=0; i < len; i++) {
    key = JSON.stringify(arr[i]);
    obj[key] = (obj[key]) ? obj[key] + 1 : 1;
  }
  for (var key in obj) {
    out.push(JSON.parse(key));
  }
  return [out, obj];
}
```

Note: You need to use JSON library for browser that's not supported JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one of methods to avoid duplicates into javascript array...and it supports for strings and numbers...

```
 var unique = function(origArr) {
    var newArray = [],
        origLen = origArr.length,
        found,
        x = 0; y = 0;

    for ( x = 0; x < origLen; x++ ) {
        found = undefined;
        for ( y = 0; y < newArray.length; y++ ) {
            if ( origArr[x] === newArray[y] ) found = true;
        }
        if ( !found) newArray.push( origArr[x] );    
    }
   return newArray;
}
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V9RBE/4/)..

Comment: Not what was asked for.

Comment: Question is not to remove duplicates but to find them. Also why don't you care about complexity yours is O(nlog(n)). also using n space.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to improve the answer from @swilliams, this will return an array without duplicates.

```
// arrays for testing
var arr = [9, 9, 111, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7];

// ascending order
var sorted_arr = arr.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;}); 

var arr_length = arr.length;
var results = [];
if(arr_length){
    if(arr_length == 1){
        results = arr;
    }else{
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            if (sorted_arr[i + 1] != sorted_arr[i]) {
                results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
            }
            // for last element
            if (i == arr.length - 2){
                results.push(sorted_arr[i+1]);
            }
        }
    }
}

alert(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one implemented using sort() and JSON.stringify()

https://gist.github.com/korczis/7598657

```
function removeDuplicates(vals) {
    var res = [];
    var tmp = vals.sort();

    for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        res.push(tmp[i]);
                    while (JSON.stringify(tmp[i]) == JSON.stringify(tmp[i + 1])) {
            i++;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
console.log(removeDuplicates([1,2,3,4,5,4,3,3,2,1,]));
```

Comment: I didn't down vote but question is to find all duplicates not remove them. Also your answer wont work even in simple examples.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [4,5,1,1,2,3,4,4,7,5,2,6,10,9];
var sorted_arr = arr.sort();
var len = arr.length;
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (sorted_arr[i + 1] !== sorted_arr[i]) {
    results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
  }
}
document.write(results);
```

Comment: This does not do what the question asks. The loop runs one step too far. This answer is substantially the same as other older answers.

Answer (score 0):

here is a small simple snippet to  find unique and duplicate values with out sorting and two loops.

```js
var _unique = function (arr) {
    var h = [], t = [];
    arr.forEach(function (n) {
        if (h.indexOf(n) == -1)
            h.push(n);
        else t.push(n);
    });
    return [h, t];
}
var result = _unique(["test",1,4,2,34,6,21,3,4,"test","prince","th",34]);
console.log("Has duplicate values : " + (result[1].length > 0))  //and you can check count of duplicate values
console.log(result[0]) //unique values
console.log(result[1]) //duplicate values
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following construction:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,5];
var duplicate = arr.filter(function(item, i, arr) {
  return -1 !== arr.indexOf(item, i + 1);
})
```

Comment: `const duplicates = Array.from(new Set(arr.filter((eg, i, ar)=> i !==ar.indexOf(eg))))` updated code with single line try it out

Answer (score 0):

using Pure Js

```
function arr(){
  var a= [1,2,3,4,5,34,2,5,7,8,6,4,3,25,8,34,56,7,8,76,4,23,34,46,575,8564,53,5345657566];
  var b= [];
  b.push(a[0]);
  var z=0;

  for(var i=0; i< a.length; i++){
      for(var j=0; j< b.length; j++){
        if(b[j] == a[i]){
          z = 0;
          break;
        }
        else
          z = 1;
      }
      if(z)
        b.push(a[i]);
    }
  console.log(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var isUnique = true;      
for (var i= 0; i< targetItems.length; i++) {
        var itemValue = $(targetItems[i]).val();
        if (targetListValues.indexOf(itemValue) >= 0) {
          isUnique = false;
           break;
        }
      targetListValues.push(itemValue);
        if (!isUnique) {
          //raise any error msg
          return false;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we output the duplicates just once per dupe.

```js
var arr = [9, 9, 9, 9, 111, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7];
arr.sort(); 

var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (arr[i + 1] == arr[i]) {
        results.push(arr[i]);
    }
}

results = Array.from(new Set(results))

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more advanced function based on number of occurences.

```
function getMostDuplicated(arr, count) {
      const result = [];
      arr.forEach((item) => {
        let i = 0;
        arr.forEach((checkTo) => {
          if (item === checkTo) {
            i++;
            if (i === count && result.indexOf(item) === -1) {
              result.push(item);
            }
          }
        });
      });
      return result;
}

arr = [1,1,1,2,5,67,3,2,3,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,4];
result = getMostDuplicated(arr, 5); // result is 1
result = getMostDuplicated(arr, 2); // result 1, 2, 3, 4
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You should add number of occurences, number of duplicates.

Comment: question is to get duplicates, please answer that only. Also your complexity is O(n^2 * result.length). It's such a worst complexity for simple task.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented it with map. It should run in O(n) time and should kinda be easy to gasp.

```js
    var first_array=[1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6];
    var find_dup=new Map;

    for (const iterator of first_array) {
            // if present value++
            if(find_dup.has(iterator)){ 
                find_dup.set(iterator,find_dup.get(iterator)+1); 
            }else{
            // else add it
                find_dup.set(iterator,1);
            }
        }
    console.log(find_dup.get(2));
```

Then you can `find_dup.get(key)` to find if it has duplicates (it should give > 1).

Answer (score 0):

Returns duplicates and preserves data type.

#### With O(4n) performance

```
const dupes = arr => {
  const map = arr.reduce((map, curr) => {
    return (map.set(curr, (map.get(curr) || 0) + 1), map)
  }, new Map());

  return Array.from(map).filter(([key, val])=> val > 1).map(([key, val]) => key)
}
```

#### With O(2n) performance

```
const dupes = arr => {
  const map = arr.reduce((map, curr) => {
    return (map.set(curr, (map.get(curr) || 0) + 1), map)
  }, new Map());

  const dupes_ = [];
  for (let [key, val] of map.entries()) {
    if (val > 1) dupes_.push(key);
  }
  return dupes_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest way to fetch duplicates/repeated values from array/string :**

```js
function getDuplicates(param) {
  var duplicates = {}

  for (var i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
    var char = param[i]
    if (duplicates[char]) {
      duplicates[char]++
    } else {
      duplicates[char] = 1
    }
  }
  return duplicates
}

console.log(getDuplicates("aeiouaeiou"));
console.log(getDuplicates(["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "a", "e"]));
console.log(getDuplicates([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return duplicates from an Array as an Array of duplicates.

```js
    const duplicates = function(arr) {
      // let try moving in pairs.. maybe that will work
      let dups = new Set(),
          r = []
      arr.sort()
      arr.reduce((pv, cv) => {
        if (pv === cv) {
          dups.add(pv)
        }
        return cv
      })
      for (let m of dups.values()) {
        r.push(m)
      }
      return r
    }
    
    console.log(duplicates([1,3,5,6,7,4,4,5,1,4,6,3,8,9,5,0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple way:

```js
function getDuplicateValues(someArray) {
 const duplicateValues = new Set([])
 const check = new Set([])
 someArray.forEach(v => {
  if (check.has(v)) {
   duplicateValues.add(v)
  } else {
   check.add(v)
  }
 })
 return Array.from(duplicateValues);
}

const result = getDuplicateValues(['coffee', 'soda', 'water', 'juice', 'water', 'water', 'coffee'])

repeated_values.textContent = JSON.stringify(result, null, '  ')
```

```html
<pre id="repeated_values"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is the most perfect one but as some users has pointed that for cases where an element is repeated more than 2 times it will gives us the array with repeated elements:

This solution covers that scenarios too::

```
const peoples = [
  {id: 1, name:"Arjun"},
  {id: 2, name:"quinze"},
  {id: 3, name:"catorze"},
  {id: 1, name:"Arjun"},
  {id: 4, name:"dezesseis"},
  {id: 1, name:"Arjun"},
  {id: 2, name:"quinze"},
  {id: 3, name:"catorzee"}
]


function repeated(ppl){

  const newppl = ppl.slice().sort((a,b) => a.id -b.id);

  let rept = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < newppl.length-1 ; i++){
    if (newppl[i+1].id == newppl[i].id){
      rept.push(newppl[i+1]);
    }
  }

  return [...new Set(rept.map(el => el.id))].map(rid => 
    rept.find(el => el.id === rid)
  );

}

repeated(peoples);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 50, 8, 5, 22, 1, 2, 511, 12, 50, 22].reduce(function (total, currentValue, currentIndex, arr) {
    if (total.indexOf(currentValue) === -1 && arr.indexOf(currentValue) !== currentIndex) 
        total.push(currentValue);
    return total;
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = ['a', 'b', 'b']

function findDuplicates(a) {
    return Object.keys(_.pickBy(_.countBy(a), x => x > 1))
}
```

https://runkit.com/nitzanav/62659f09bd2d5f0008ef46d4

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the duplicate elements in a given array:

```js
let name = ['satya', 'amit', 'aditya', 'abhay', 'satya', 'amit'];
let dup = [];
let uniq = [];
name.forEach((item, index) => {
  if(!uniq.includes(item)) {
    uniq[index] = item;
  }
  if (name.indexOf(item, index + 1) != -1) {
    dup[index] = item;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just need to find what the duplicated values are - I don't actually need their indexes or how many times they are duplicated.

A fun and simple task with many hard-to-read answers...

**Typescript**

```js
function getDuplicatedItems<T>(someArray: T[]): T[] {
    // create a set to iterate through (we only need to check each value once)
    const itemSet = new Set<T>(someArray);

    // from that Set, we check if any of the items are duplicated in someArray
    const duplicatedItems = [...itemSet].filter(
        (item) => someArray.indexOf(item) !== someArray.lastIndexOf(item)
    );

    return duplicatedItems;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```js
function getDuplicatedItems(someArray) {
    // check for misuse if desired
    // if (!Array.isArray(someArray)) {
    //     throw new TypeError(`getDuplicatedItems requires an Array type, received ${typeof someArray} type.`);
    // }
    const itemSet = new Set(someArray);
    const duplicatedItems = [...itemSet].filter(
        (item) => someArray.indexOf(item) !== someArray.lastIndexOf(item)
    );
    return duplicatedItems;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Is the answer.

```js
const array = [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 5];
const results = array.filter((value, index, arr) => arr.indexOf(value) != index);
console.log(results)
//[ 1, 3 ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's one without using a temp Array to store the non-duplicate ones:

```
// simple duplicate removal for non-object types
Array.prototype.removeSimpleDupes = function() {
    var i, cntr = 0, arr = this, len = arr.length;

    var uniqueVal = function(val,n,len) { // remove duplicates
        var dupe = false;
            for (i = n; i < len; i++) { 
                if (typeof arr[i]!=="undefined" && val===arr[i]) { arr.splice(i,1); dupe = true; }
            }
        return (dupe) ? arr.length : len;
    };

    while (cntr < len) {
        len = uniqueVal(arr[cntr],cntr+1,len);
        cntr++;
    }

    return arr;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function remove_dups(arrayName){
  var newArray = new Array();

  label:for(var i=0; i<arrayName.length; i++ ){  

     for(var j=0; j<newArray.length;j++ ){
       if(newArray[j]==arrayName[i]){
         continue label;
       }
     }

     newArray[newArray.length] = arrayName[i];

  }

  return newArray;
}
```

Comment: -1: Doesn't answer the question asked, which was to identify dupes, not remove them. You should probably also include some text describing your solution.

Answer (score -1):

Surprised no one posted `this solution`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
       var list = [100,33,45,54,9,12,80,100];
       var newObj = {};
       var newArr = [];
        for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
          newObj[list[i]] = i;               
        }
        for(var j in newObj){
            newArr.push(j);  
        }
       console.log(newArr);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the question asks.

Comment: @ScottSaunders: Easiest way to find duplicate values in a JavaScript array

Comment: The question is asking how to show the duplicate values, not the unique values.

Answer (score -1):

```
var a= [1, 2,2,3,3,4,4,4];
var m=[];
var n = [];
a.forEach(function(e) {
  if(m.indexOf(e)=== -1) {
    m.push(e);
}else if(n.indexOf(e)=== -1){
    n.push(e);
}

});
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, one should always consider adding an explanation to it.

Comment: Iterating array and storing the unique values in array M and duplicate values in n

Answer (score -1):

You can proceed by comparing index:

```
function getDuplicate(array) {
    return array.filter((value, index) => array.value !== index)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**We will use Javascript ES6 Functionality to do magic!**

```
var arr = [9, 9, 111, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7];
const filtered = arr.filter((value, index) => {
 return arr.indexOf(value) >= index;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/97Lxupnz/

Answer (score -1):

```
var arr = ['a','b','c','a'];

arr.filter( (item , index ) => {  
console.log(item , index , arr.indexOf(item) , arr.indexOf( item ) == index);
return index == arr.indexOf(item)
 } );
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'];

function unique(array) {
    var unique_arr = [];
    array.forEach(function(i, e) {
        if (unique_arr.indexOf(i)===-1) unique_arr.push(i);
    });
    return unique_arr;
}
console.log(unique(array));
```

Answer (score -1):

This was asked me in an interview, My answer is,

```
List<int> getDublicates(List<int> x)
{
   List<int> result = new List<int>();
   while (x.Count>0)
   {
      int d = x[0];
      x.Remove(x[0]);
      if (x.Contains(d)) 
      result.Add(d);
   }
   return result;
}
```

it have good performance

Comment: This is Java, right?

Comment: it is C# but Java has similar syntax rules to C#. You can use it for both

Answer (score -3):

In this post was useful for duplication check if u are using Jquery.

[How to find the duplicates in an array using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346547/how-to-find-the-duplicates-in-an-array-using-jquery)

```
var unique_values = {}; var list_of_values = []; $('input[name$="recordset"]').     each(function(item) {          if ( ! unique_values[item.value] ) {             unique_values[item.value] = true;             list_of_values.push(item.value);         } else {             // We have duplicate values!         }     });
```

Answer (score -3):

```
//program to find the duplicate elements in arraylist

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DistinctEle 
{ 
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Enter elements");
        ArrayList<Integer> abc=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> ab=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
        int b;
        for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
        {
            b=a.nextInt();
            if(!abc.contains(b))
            {
                abc.add(b);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("duplicate elements"+b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider explaining the code you've offered in your answer.

Comment: The question was regarding JavaScript not Java.